# selectize.js: Fetch all selected values from selectized dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have multiple select options have different classes and names and I am using selectize library to allow the user to search. I want to get the selected values on click of a button. Right now, I have tried the following code

```js
$(window).bind("load", function()
{
    var selectize_search_1 = $('.selectize_search_1').selectize(
    {
        sortField: 'text'
    });
});
function fetch_cars()
{
    var cars_value = $('.selectize_search_1')[0].selectize.items;
    alert (cars_value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectize_search_1" name="cars[]" required>
    <option value="">Select Car</option>
    <option value="C1">Car 1</option>
    <option value="C2">Car 2</option>
    <option value="C3">Car 3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="selectize_search_1" name="cars[]" required>
    <option value="">Select Car</option>
    <option value="C1">Car 1</option>
    <option value="C2">Car 2</option>
    <option value="C3">Car 3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<button type="button" onclick="fetch_cars();">Fetch Cars</button>
```

So, lets suppose i select car 1 and car 2 from the dropdowns, but using the above code, it only return me the selected value in the first dropdown but not both selected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
$(function(){
   var selectize_search_1 = $('.selectize_search_1').selectize({sortField: 'text'});
});

function fetch_cars(){
   var cars_value = $('select.selectize_search_1').get().map(el=>el.value).join(",");
   console.log(cars_value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectize_search_1" name="cars[]" required>
    <option value="">Select Car</option>
    <option value="C1">Car 1</option>
    <option value="C2">Car 2</option>
    <option value="C3">Car 3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="selectize_search_1" name="cars[]" required>
    <option value="">Select Car</option>
    <option value="C1">Car 1</option>
    <option value="C2">Car 2</option>
    <option value="C3">Car 3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<button type="button" onclick="fetch_cars();">Fetch Cars</button>
```

If you want the values of all select boxes you will need to `.map()` over them.

The `jQueryObject.get()` will extract the element selection from the jQuery object, so the following `.map()` is a plain ("Vanilla") `Array.prototype.map()` again.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. Create unique `<select>` class.

I added a working version. Has two unique `<select>` classes now, with the corresponding jQuery.

```js
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  var selectize_search_1 = $('.selectize_search_1').selectize({
    sortField: 'text'
  });
  //create new selectize...
  //create new selectize...
  var selectize_search_2 = $('.selectize_search_2').selectize({
    sortField: 'text'
  });

});

function fetch_cars() {
  var cars_value = $('.selectize_search_1')[0].selectize.items;
  //make another var...
  //make another var...
  var cars_value2 = $('.selectize_search_2')[0].selectize.items;
  //retrieve new selectize...
  //retrieve new selectize...
  alert("select1: "+cars_value + " select2: " + cars_value2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectize_search_1" name="cars[]" required>
  <option value="">Select Car</option>
  <option value="C1">Car 1</option>
  <option value="C2">Car 2</option>
  <option value="C3">Car 3</option>
</select>
<br />
<!-- add new class -->
<!-- add new class -->
<select class="selectize_search_2" name="cars[]" required>
<!-- add new class -->
<!-- add new class -->

  <option value="">Select Car</option>
  <option value="C1">Car 1</option>
  <option value="C2">Car 2</option>
  <option value="C3">Car 3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<button type="button" onclick="fetch_cars();">Fetch Cars</button>
```